# RS232 P3 protocol?

Tags: serial-port

Here is an except from a manual for a piece of hardware I wish to develop software for. However have no idea what the P3 rs232 protocol is. Hopefully someone here can help me out.

> Protocol RS232: This is used to select the protocol on the RS232
> interface. There are 3 options:
>
> Enhanced - This protocol is here only
> for compatibility reasons. Not all
> features are available via this
> protocol.
>
> P3 - If you are a software
> developer this is the preferred
> protocol to use. This protocol is also
> used for software like ‘Racewave’.
>
> Remote - Allows the host computer to
> select the protocol by using a
> command. Use this setting when 12 used
> with Orbits.

Comment: What exactly is this "piece of hardware" you speak of?

Comment: A mylaps (AMB) transponder decoder
http://www.mylaps.com/kb/en/b2b/Manuals/MyLaps%20Decoder%20Manual.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RS232 means, in general, "serial port". An euphemism for bi-directional data link over two wires.

P3 is probably an applicative term of the tool you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

P3 is a protocol used for data transmission specially in telecommunication networks such as message handling systems, X.400. P3.2EX. can be used to send a control commands from a server device to a slave device and to get the readings back from the slave. Maybe it has some other usages I am not aware of.

Comment: While this might be true, in this case P3 refers to a proprietary protocol invented by AMB-i.t. and has nothing to do with the X.400 P3.2EX protocol, as far as I can tell.